# mongodb java driver 3.6 get nested field value

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I got an annoying problem with `MongoDB Java Driver 3.6.1` (using `libGDX`, but that does not seem to be part of the problem):

Code looks like this

```
FindIterable<Document> userDoc = dbConnector.getUserCollection().find(eq("name", username));
Gdx.app.log("Document: ", userDoc.first().toJson());
highscore = userDoc.first().getInteger("highscore.value");
```

The Log displays this correct document:

```
Document: : { 
    "_id" : { 
        "$oid" : "5a6f83ee63de88719051ff23" 
    }, 
    "name" : "NewApiT", 
    "preferences" : { 
        "sound" : true, 
        "music" : true, 
        "volSound" : 1.0, 
        "volMusic" : 0.05, 
        "charSkin" : 1, 
        "showFpsCounter" : true,
        "useMonochromeShader" : false 
    }, 
    "highscore" : { 
        "value" : 0 
    } 
}
```

But I always get a NullPointerException for the highscore value. The value is 0 in the database and of type integer32. highscore is an int variable declared with

```
int highscore = -1;
```

a few lines before.

All the Documents are build like this:

```
Document newUser = new Document("name", username)
                .append("preferences", new Document("sound", true)
                        .append("music", true)
                        .append("volSound", (double)1)
                        .append("volMusic", 0.05)
                        .append("charSkin", 1)
                        .append("showFpsCounter", true)
                        .append("useMonochromeShader", false))
                .append("highscore", new Document("value", 0));
        dbConnector.getUserCollection().insertOne(newUser);
```

I hope anyone got some suggestions what the problem is.

Comment: That is expected behaviour. Try `highscore = userDoc.first().get("highscore", Document.class).getInteger("value");` or `((Document)userDoc.first().get("highscore")).getInteger("value")`

Comment: Thanks that worked.. I updated from Driver Version 2.13 and there seem to be much more changes than I expected..